# how to put network path for local maven repository \\user023\share\folder

Tags: android, maven, repository

We have local network with bunch of users connected together.
And we can access shared files like `\\user023\share\folder\test.txt`.
How can i use this address to make local maven repository or how can i use `maven { url 'path to network address'}` ?

Comment: Never share things like that...Local repository is as the name implies local and as JF Meier already stated does not work...Apart from that: Why do you need that?

Comment: i need to publish my library on server and other user use it to build project .

Comment: Then simply start using a repository manager and this will solve all this kind of problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
maven { url 'file:///[Path-to-Repo]'}
```

For example:
If you repo were located at `'\\Sever\Developer Repos\m2'`:

The Maven reference in the repository section of your `build.gradle` would look like:

```
maven { url 'file:///Sever/Developer%2520Repos/m2'}
```

A few caveats:

- It is advised to do what other suggest and setup a 'real' repository.
  if that is not possible, then enter into the rest of this at your own
  risk.
- Use the '/' character in your paths.
- Spaces in filenames need to be designated with their unicode escaped equivalency.
- The m2 repo needs to be an actual Maven repo with the appropriate file structure,.pom files etc.
- Never WRITE to a repo like this with a build script when there are multiple users utilizing this repo. This will most certainly cause corruption for at least a portion of the repo. In fact, I would lock the file structure as read-only if possible to prevent this from happening and force manual updates to the repo as necessary.
- This information is for gradle 6.3 with the Android 3.6.3 gradle build tools. This has broke in the past and so be sure to use a gradle wrapper with your project to ensure build compatibility as you move forward.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: Local Maven repositories are *not* thread safe.

If you run more than one build at the same time on the same Maven local repository, this can lead to inconsistent states.

So it is not a good idea to share a local repository between several users.

Comment: is it possible though?

Comment: I'm just trying to avoid using IIS . also there is not going to be multiple build at the same time

Comment: Did you try something like `-Dmaven.repo.local=\\user023\share\folder` as parameter for `mvn`?

Comment: i dont have Maven installed i use maven integrated in InteliJ.

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ but I guess that you can call Maven commands with parameters from there. In an case: Don't use local repositories to share artifacts. Use Nexus or Artifactory for that.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with our colleagues that have suggested to avoid using this kind of solution:

Local repository is first of all:

- **Local** - Its only for developer to update this repository. Its not "multi-access" safe.
  Even if many threads from the same maven process try to download artifacts to it (or in general change it) this sometimes can be problematic. I'm not talking about multi-JVM concurrent access, its just not designed to be like this.
- **Cache** - intended for fast access during the compilation and other tasks that the developers do. If you use a distributed FS it may slow down the compilation and the developers won't use it.

So if your goal is to

> i need to publish my library on server and other user use it to build project

1. Use tools like Nexus or Artifactory to host your artifacts intended for shared usage
2. If these tools are not available - use some web server with HTTP access and configure maven to download from there.
3. If this is impossible  - instruct the developers to run `mvn install` per new version of the shared resources. Then they'll get in their local repo an application of the reproducible version.

Of course the option 3 is a really bad one, option 2 is much better, but option 1 is the best one you can get.

Comment: Im going to use IIS but somehow it dos not recognizing the repository

Comment: Sorry, but: What is IIS?